# Erroneous error in AD FS 2.0 Federation Server Configuration Wizard

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net-3.5, adfs

I am trying to set up AD FS 2.0 on a Windows Server 008 R2 Enterprise, but I am stuck on getting an error when trying to run the "AD FS 2.0 Federation Server Configuration Wizard":

[image: Error message]

The error states that "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 is required for the initial configuration wizard to run". I am absolutely certain that .NET 3.5 is installed on the server, yet the error message pops up, preventing me to complete the installation. The error dialog suggests "re-running the AD FS Installer". I have tried this, but it does not change a thing.

Has anyone seen this erroneous error before? Any ideas  how to make it go away?

Comment: Do you have .NET 3.5 installed via the Application Server role, or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if the .Net 3.5.1 shows up as an installed feature in server manager? I also recommend installing any required updates (skip optional) for .Net framework suggested by windows update. There were some security updates as I recall but the presence of .net 3.5.1 suggests the required service pack is installed.

As a last resort I'd get the .net framework installation checked out using the .NET Framework Setup Verification Tool at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx .